# Database relation

Tags: relational-database, database-schema

I'm newbie in databases and I'm designing database and struggling with one problem. So in my application there are trainings which could have many students and also those students can take a exams in those training and gets grades for it. So I come to conclusion that I got many-to-many relation in training-student and exam-training, but now I have no idea where should I keep students scores. Could you help me to resolve my doubts? Here is simple diagram I made.

[image: Database diagram]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about you put it into a relationship the connects `Training_Exam` and `Student` together?

```
Student_Training_Exam(student_id, training_exam_id, score)
```

This would tell you, which student attended which training_exam, and the score he achieved in that training exam.

Answer (score 0):

How about this kind of entity-relationship diagram?

```
               (Score)
                  |
[Student]--*--<TookExam>--*--[Training]
```

The `Score` is an attribute of the `TookExam` relationship, which relates a `Student` to a `Training`. In a relational database, you might have a `TookExam` table with the three columns `StudentID`, `TrainingID`, and `Score`.